# How to solve CORS problems in java vert.x

Tags: rest, cors, angular5, vert.x

I have a vertx backend server on localhost:8080 answering REST request.

When sending a GET request, everything works fine.

But on a DELETE request with params I get CORS errors...

My backend server looks like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("<h1>Hello from my first Vert.x 3 application</h1>");
    });

    router.get("/api/whiskies").handler(this::getAll);
    router.delete("/api/whiskies/:id").handler(this::deleteOne);

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(
            config().getInteger("http.port", 8080), result -> {
                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    fut.complete();
                } else {
                    fut.fail(result.cause());
                }
            });
}

private void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                             .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                             .end(Json.encodePrettily(products.values()));
}


private void deleteOne(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    Integer idAsInteger = Integer.valueOf(routingContext.request().getParam("id"));
    products.remove(idAsInteger);
    routingContext.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                             .setStatusCode(204).end();
    }
}
```

I hoped, that the .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") part would fix all CORS problems, but somehow that only works for the GET part of the code...

My front end is an Angular5 application running on localhost:4200 looking like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
  
  getWhiskies() {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/whiskies');
  }
  
  deleteWhisky(id :number) {
   return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/whiskies/' + id);
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to fix it by defining allowed methods as well as the "Content-Type" header.

See the following link for references:

[github vertx-examples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/cors/Server.java)

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x provides you with a CORS handler out of the box:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

So I added the io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler in the way you described. I hope that is the correct one?

Anyhow, that alone didnt solve my problem...